# How to authenticate users by their role declarative?

Tags: java, authentication, jsf, jboss, seam

How can Seam be configured to use different security-constraints for different web-resource-collections?

In `web.xml` I included a sections like

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AdminPages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

If I omit the configuration above (web.xml). The user is authenticated (only password) using JAAS. I would prefer not write code for Authenticatin, I really only need to check that the user has the required role (admin).

In Seam this doesn't work like expected. I receive HTTP-Errorcode 403 while trying to access the pages in `/secure/*`

I configured in `components.xml` This works when web.xml is not changed.

```
<security:identity jaas-config-name="admins" />
```

And `jboss-web.xml`

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/admins</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

The question is where do I configure the role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set up a new security domain on JBoss.

For instance:

```
<policy>
    <application-policy name="testUsersRoles">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
                          flag="required">
                <module-option name="usersProperties">usersb64.properties</module-option>
                <module-option name="hashAlgorithm">MD5</module-option>
                <module-option name="hashEncoding">base64</module-option>
                <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">nobody</module-option>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
    </application-policy>
</policy>
```

(at the conf/login-config.xml file of your JBoss instance).

You have more information here: [Security on JBoss](http://docs.jboss.com/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch8.chapter.html)

**UPDATE:**

About the "use different security-constraints for different web-resource-collections" part of your question, you can set it adding a different "security-constraint" for every group of resources to control:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AdminPages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>CommonUserPages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/common/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>commonUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <role-name>commonUser</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Please, note that both roles will be extracted by the asociated LoginModule at login time. So when your LoginModule authenticates an user, it retrieves the set of roles which this user belongs to.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes I did set up the application-policy, as I noted it works for authenticate the user. The issue is that I need to check the role also.

Comment: The login module, aside the authentication, takes care of authorization (loads the profiles of the user at the user identity, in a Principal Object linked to the user session). Depending on the implementation selected, it's configured in a different way (groups for LdapLoginModule, roles.properties for simple UsersRolesLoginModule, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Use custom Indentity with postAuthenticate method.

```
<security:identity jaas-config-name="admins" class="my.Identity"/>
```

Example code:

```
package my;

public class Identity extends org.jboss.seam.security.Identity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void postAuthenticate() {
        super.postAuthenticate();
        if(isLoggedIn() && !hasRole("admin")) {
            unAuthenticate();
        }
    }
}
```